# One account for several apps

Tags: android, authentication

I want to create several apps they could be installed seperately or all together on the same smartphone. And I would like to user the same account for all of them.

For example, I would like to have applications A, B and C. I the user chooses to log in/out through the application A, he/she should be authomatically logged in/out from A and C and doesn't have to fill the "Log In" form or press "Log out" button.

What is the best and safest way to implement it?

1. use an external file? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal
2. is it possible with the help of account manager?
3. another option?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do so with the help of the [Account Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) and [Intents](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html). There's a pretty good tutorial for the account manager [here](http://blog.udinic.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator/).

- Firstly, you're gonna have to create an account from one of your apps (say app A)
- When one logs in one of your apps, you'll have to allow B and C to receive Intents (you'll probably want to put your account related data in it) and save their state
- Finally, when the user logs out from A, you'll have to send an intent once again to tell your other apps about it.

This might not be the best solution, but it still is one.